# How to update an attribute within a row on click

Tags: outsystems

I have a page which manage student's attendance. By the default the status of the attendance is pending. Beside each student name is an tick and cross. I want the attendance attribute of the student to change to attended and not attended when the user click the tick and cross respectively.

So far I have only been able to update the student's attendance the database by having the user fill up a new form and sending it the server function. I would like to skip this process so their is hassle for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two links (one for tick and another for cross) to a [screen action](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/11/Reference/OutSystems_Language/Logic/Implementing_Logic/Logic_Elements/Screen_Action) with two input parameters, `studentId` and `AttendanceStatusId`. This screen action should update the Student record in the database. So, when the user clicks tick or cross, you update that record. After the update, you should use an [`Ajax Refresh`](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/11/Reference/OutSystems_Language/Traditional_Web/Web_Logic_Tools/Ajax_Refresh) widget to reflect the changes on your data grid.